# SimpleXML is installed yet Symfony tells me it isn't, why?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to install Symfony, but when I run `symfony check:requirements`, I get this error :

```
* simplexml_import_dom() must be available
   > Install and enable the SimpleXML extension.
```

Yet, when I run `apt search php|grep xml`, it appears that I do have SimpleXML installed for PHP8.2, which is my PHP version.

So where's the problem here ? I have tried looking up how to enable SimpleXML, but the only answer I get is that it's enabled by default, which doesn't help much.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you only **install** the extension, or also **enable** it? Why not check `phpinfo()`  for a list of enabled extensions?

Comment: Are you sure that `symfony check:requirements` run PHP 8.2? You can see the modules with `php -m`.

Comment: `apt search php|grep xml` shows you what you *can* install, not what you *have* installed. Check for active extensions with `php -m` on console. For SimpleXml do `php -m | grep Simple`

Comment: I have done the php -m thing and I do indeed have SimpleXML

Comment: If you are really sure that you have SimpleXML installed and activated, and that the `symfony` script runs with the PHP version where this is configured, you should report this incorrect behaviour at Symfony's issue tracker

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> apt install php-xml

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, it appeared that symfony check:requirement was started on the wrong php version. It is shown at the top :

> PHP is using the following php.ini file: /etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini

And I use php8.2 I had problems about that in my project, I don't know exactly what resolved the problem but I deleted completly php-xml and reinstalled it, and I changed the php version used by the system.

Now the check requirement don't pass because it's on the wrong version but my project works again. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command:

```
sudo apt install php<YOUR_CURRENT_PHP_VERSION>-xml
```

Example:

```
sudo apt install php8.2-xml
```

It works for me!